# Spring boot, disable security for tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I use spring boot version "1.3.0.M5" (I also tried version "1.2.5.RELEASE"). I added spring security:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and code:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootMainApplication {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootMainApplication.class, args);
  }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
  }
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/api/sampleentity").authenticated()
    .and().authorizeRequests()
    .and().formLogin().permitAll()
    .and().logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
  }
  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/sampleentity")
public class SampleEntityController {
  @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET)
  public Iterable<SampleEntity> getAll() {
    return ImmutableSet.of();
  }
  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public SampleEntity create(@RequestBody SampleEntity sampleEntity) {
    return sampleEntity;
  }
}
```

and test that is failing when /api/sampleentity is access: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 403 Forbidden (...)

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootMainApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
public class SampleEntityTest {
  @Value("${local.server.port}")
  private int port;
  private String url;
  private RestTemplate restTemplate;
  @Autowired
  private ApplicationContext context;
  @BeforeClass
  public static void authenticate(){
//ONE TRY
//        Authentication authentication =
//                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password",
//                                                        AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER")); //tried "ROLE_USER"
//        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
  }
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    url = String.format("http://localhost:%s/api/sampleentity", port);
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
//ANOTHER TRY
//        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = context.getBean(AuthenticationManager.class);
//        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
//                .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password", AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"))); //tried "ROLE_USER"
//        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
  }
  //THIS METHOD SHOULD WORK !
  @Test
//ANOTHER TRY
//@WithMockUser(username="user",password = "password", roles={"USER"})//tried "ROLE_USER"
  public void testEntity_create() throws Exception {
    SampleEntity sampleEntity = create("name", 1);
    ResponseEntity<SampleEntity> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, sampleEntity, SampleEntity.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED, response.getStatusCode());
  }
  private SampleEntity create(String name, int id) {
    SampleEntity entity = new SampleEntity();
    entity.setName(name);
    entity.setId(id);
    return entity;
  }
}
```

When I run application from main() and access url:
http://localhost:8080/api/sampleentity
I am redirected to login page.

How can I run my test and disable security or just log in user ?

--my solution: exclude security from the test using profiles:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootMainApplication {body the same}

@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
@Profile("!test")
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {body the same}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootMainApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class SampleEntityTest {body the same}
```

Comment: HI! do you have any solution for his issue : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774909/how-to-bypass-or-skip-customfilter-in-mockito-with-springboot-applicaiton .      any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I see you can apparently use the [`@WithMockUser`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test-method-withmockuser) from the documentation with your test.

Answer (score 3):

You have to do some changes to your config and test to solve your problem(s).

First I'll explain why your solution isn't working:

1. The Spring `RestTemplate` class is a possible way to access your REST service but lacks some header informations the way it is constructed (Which doesn't mean it's impossible with the `RestTemplate`). Thats why the authentication didn't work.
2. My first solution attempt isn't working because of the usage of the `RestTemplate` class, as the `RestTemplate` request is likely to create a new session. It sets an entirely different environment. My code works if you want to test Methods secured with the `@PreAuthorize` annotation but only if you want to execute such a method directly in your test and you need a valid authentication.
3. You can't automatically authorize any user as of your current spring security configuration.

Second, here are the necessary changes to your code:

First the configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
  auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER" );
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.httpBasic().and().csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/sampleentity").authenticated()
    .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/users").hasRole("ADMIN")
    .and().formLogin().permitAll()
    .and().logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout")
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
  }

  @Override
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}
```

I had to add httpBasic Authentication support (to enable authentication via http header attribute) and I disabled csrf tokens (the latter just for convenience, you should reenable them according to criticality of your application).

And second the Testclass:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.IntegrationTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;
import org.springframework.mock.http.MockHttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.post;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.*;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SpringBootMainApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest({ "server.port=0" })
public class SampleEntityTest {

private String url;
private MockMvc mockMvc;
private HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter;

private MediaType contentType = new MediaType(
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(),
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
private Filter springSecurityFilterChain;

@Autowired
void setConverters(HttpMessageConverter<?>[] converters) {
    for (HttpMessageConverter hmc : Arrays.asList(converters)) {
        if (hmc instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
            this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter = hmc;
        }
    }

    Assert.assertNotNull("the JSON message converter must not be null",
            this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter);
}

@Before
public void setUp() {
    url = "/api/sampleentity";
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilters(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}

@Test
public void testEntityGet() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(
            get(url)
            .with(httpBasic("user", "password")))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}

@Test
public void testEntityPost() throws Exception {
    SampleEntity sampleEntity = new SampleEntity();
    sampleEntity.setName("name");
    sampleEntity.setId(1);
    String json = json(sampleEntity);
    mockMvc.perform(
            post(url)
            .contentType(contentType)
            .content(json)
            .with(httpBasic("user", "password")))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());
}

protected String json(Object o) throws IOException {
    MockHttpOutputMessage mockHttpOutputMessage = new MockHttpOutputMessage();
    this.mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.write(o,
            MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, mockHttpOutputMessage);
    return mockHttpOutputMessage.getBodyAsString();
}
```

}

I have used the spring/ spring security test approach here.

**Versions used:**

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

If you want to test your rest api i can recommend you the Postman plugin for Chrome. As that can help you identify the problem much faster.

I hope this helps you to finally solve your problem.

Comment: I updated my post. I tried your advice, but I still have 403 Forbidden. What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Can you try it without the @WithMockUser ? And can you provide your AuthenticationProvider if you have a custom implementation?

Comment: Hi, this 3 ties were made separately (so I commented @WithMockUser). I don't use any custom AuthenticationProvider.

Comment: Has the authentication worked when you started the actual application?

Oh and you have to add the ROLE_ prefix to the Role but see the edit of my answer for that

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I updated the code in the question (almost everything is in the post). I tried your advice, but result is the same. 
Please read code once again, I hope I made it cleaner.

Comment: I rewrote the answer completely and tested the code on my local machine it should work now.

Comment: Thank you for the help. 
I found my solution as well. You can read it from the updated message. Once again thanks for involvement.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see what's being auto-configured, launch your web app and access the autoconfig endpoint (e.g., http://localhost:8080/autoconfig). Then search for '`Security`' to see which '`AutoConfiguration`' classes are being detected.

You can then disable auto-configuration of security by excluding those classes like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementSecurityAutoConfiguration.class })
```

Of course, you won't want to exclude them for production deployments. Thus you'll need to have a separate `@Configuration` class for production and tests.

**Or** if you want a detailed answer go for below-mentioned steps

---

Add annotation `@Profile(value = {"development", "production"})` to my implementation of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Profile(value = {"development", "production"})
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

Now, in test/resources, create application-test.yml to define properties for test profile and add this -

```
# Security enable/disable
security:
  basic:
    enabled: false
```

Now, to your test cases, add this annotation to apply the active profile @ActiveProfiles(value = "test"). This is how my class looked -

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles(value = "test")
@IntegrationTest({"server.port=0"})
public class SampleControllerIntegrationTest {
```

Doing this will disabled security for tests. 
Best of luck!!!